# Select elements with between between not work in SQLite

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

Following table contains my SQLite-Database on Android:

```
 >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@9f3d273
0 {
   id=1543948972569
   relationItemID=-1
   degree=-1
}
1 {
   id=-1
   relationItemID=1543948972569
   degree=1
}
2 {
   id=1543948972569
   relationItemID=1543948978808
   degree=1
}
3 {
   id=1543948978808
   relationItemID=1543948972569
   degree=-1
}
<<<<<
```

The SQLite-Query

```
SELECT id FROM itemsHierarchy 
WHERE id = 1543948972569 AND degree BETWEEN 0 AND -128
```

Returns an empty cursor even though it should find `id` of first entry.
But if I use '<' instead of 'BETWEEN 0 AND -128' like below, it works.

```
SELECT id FROM itemsHierarchy WHERE id = 1543948972569 AND degree < 0;
```

Did I do something wrong or is it a problem of SQLite?

Comment: Did you try BETWEEN -128 AND 0 ?

Comment: @0X0nosugar That's it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be -

```
    SELECT id 
    FROM itemsHierarchy 
    WHERE id = 1543948972569 
    AND degree BETWEEN -128 AND 0
```